# Raster image does not fit in folium map (leaflet.js)

Tags: python, python-xarray, folium, cartopy, rasterio

I am trying to plot a raster image from netcdf file in leaflet but its not fit correct in the map. I appreciate any help, maybe solution is projection with rasterio or geopandas. The code I use:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import folium

# geting Tmax
# you can download netcdf file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7oxk8q3kh4ozs7/Tmax_daily_UT_Brazil_v2.1_19900101_19991231.nc?dl=0
path = '/home/'
data = xr.open_mfdataset(path + 'Tmax_daily_UT_Brazil_v2.1_19800101_19891231.nc', combine='by_coords').Tmax

data2plot = np.flipud(data.isel(time=0).values.astype(np.float64))
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(data.longitude.values.astype(np.float64), data.latitude.values.astype(np.float64))

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('cubehelix')
normed_data = (data2plot - np.nanmin(data2plot)) / (np.nanmax(data2plot) - np.nanmin(data2plot))
colored_data = cm(normed_data)

m = folium.Map(location=[lat.mean(), lon.mean()], zoom_start=4)
folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
    image=colored_data,
    bounds=[[lat.min(), lon.min()], [lat.max(), lon.max()]],
    opacity=0.5
).add_to(m)

m.save('test_xarray_folium.html')
```

As you can see below, the image does not fit correct in the map.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution base in:
https://github.com/ocefpaf/folium_notebooks/blob/master

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import folium
from cartopy.img_transform import warp_array
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.cm

# based in https://github.com/ocefpaf/folium_notebooks/blob/master/test_image_overlay_geodetic.ipynb
# get data
path = '/home/'
data = xr.open_mfdataset(path + 'Tmax_daily_UT_Brazil_v2.1_19800101_19891231.nc', combine='by_coords').Tmax
data2plot = np.flipud(data.isel(time=0).values.astype(np.float64))
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(data.longitude.values.astype(np.float64), data.latitude.values.astype(np.float64))
source_extent = [lon.min(), lon.max(), lat.min(), lat.max()]
normed_data = (data2plot - np.nanmin(data2plot)) / (np.nanmax(data2plot) - np.nanmin(data2plot))
cm = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('cubehelix')
colored_data = cm(normed_data)

m = folium.Map(location=[lat.mean(), lon.mean()], zoom_start=4)
folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(colored_data,
                     [[lat.min(), lon.min()], [lat.max(), lon.max()]],
                     mercator_project=True,
                     opacity=0.5).add_to(m)

m.save('test_xarray_folium.html')
```